# MIPS has been used a multiprocessor architecture in the past. Is anyone using it in a multicore SoC?

Tags: embedded-systems, multi-core

I have been reading about the MIPS architecture and learned that it has been used a multiprocessor architecture in the past.  Is anyone presently using it in a multicore SoC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Loongson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loongson): both multi-core and with MIPS  architecture. It seems that it is developed in China mainly by Chinese engineers and academics but also is the result of a public-private partnership.